# Not Displaying Results with Inner Join 3 Tables

Tags: php, mysqli, inner-join

I am trying to inner join 3 tables that is from OS TICKET Database.

The code I am using is `$qry = "SELECT qbcd_user_email.address, qbcd_user_email.user_id FROM qbcd_user_email INNER JOIN qbcd_user ON qbcd_user.id = qbcd_user_email.user_id INNER JOIN  qbcd_ticket ON qbcd_ticket.user_id WHERE (qbcd_user_email.address = '.$email.') ORDER BY qbcd_ticket.ticket_id DESC";`

Code is returning:

```
string(287) "SELECT qbcd_user_email.address, qbcd_user_email.user_id FROM qbcd_user_email INNER JOIN qbcd_user ON qbcd_user.id = qbcd_user_email.user_id INNER JOIN qbcd_ticket ON qbcd_ticket.user_id WHERE (qbcd_user_email.address = '.patrick.kershner@gmail.com.') ORDER BY qbcd_ticket.ticket_id DESC"
```

but it is not displaying anything in the while clause:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo $row['qbcd_ticket.number]."<br>";}
```

I am not sure what is going on, or why its not displaying the results.

Can someone check out my code above and verify?

Comment: What did you try with `$result` variable?

Comment: `$qry = "SELECT qbcd_user_email.address, qbcd_user_email.user_id, qbcd_ticket.number, qbcd_ticket.id FROM qbcd_user_email INNER JOIN qbcd_user ON qbcd_user.id = qbcd_user_email.user_id INNER JOIN  qbcd_ticket ON qbcd_ticket.user_id WHERE (qbcd_user_email.address = '$email') ORDER BY qbcd_ticket.ticket_id DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $qry);
var_dump($qry)."<br>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 echo $row['qbcd_ticket.number']."<br>"; 
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the number to your selected properties

```
$qry = "SELECT qbcd_user_email.address, qbcd_user_email.user_id, qbcd_ticket.number FROM qbcd_user_email INNER JOIN qbcd_user ON qbcd_user.id = qbcd_user_email.user_id INNER JOIN  qbcd_ticket ON qbcd_ticket.user_id WHERE (qbcd_user_email.address = '.$email.') ORDER BY qbcd_ticket.ticket_id DESC"
```

Comment: I tried that, and updated it, I think its in my where loop, or in the actual qry itself.  Ill add the Tables in a comment below.

Answer (score 0):

the first table is:

```
qbcd_ticket:
rows:

ticket_id | number | user_id | user_email_id | status_id | dept_id | and more...
5     |  762086|   2     |      0    |      1|  1  |    


the next is qbcd_user_email
rows:
id | user_id | flags | address
2  |    2    |  0    |  example@demo.com

the last is: qbcd_user
id | org_id | default_email_id | status | name              | created             | updated 
2  |    0   |   2          |     0  |  Patrick Kershner | 2017-03-03 10:44:28 | 2017-03-03 10:44:28
```

The information that I need to display, is all corresponding Tickets associated with the customer where it = the email address.

the only static variable that will not change is `$_SESSION['user_email'];` which is logged by logging into the members area.